# Flutter 1.5 - Is there a way to update files on the assets folder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a simple app that generates sentences from a txt file.
i want to have the option to check if there is a new version of the txt file on a server and replace it.

is it possible to replace the file on the assets folder during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

No not possible. You should save that txt and any newer version of it into the apps application documents directory.

You can read more about it here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: I see, I guess I need to understand the difference between the assets directory and the Documents directory to know when to use which one